# Выполнить несколько php файла

Tags: php, html

в нижеуказаном коде можно ли реализовать выполнение нескольких php файлов нажатием на буттон?

```
 <form action="file_1.php, file_2.php, file_3.php ..." method="POST">
    <textarea name="username" rows="1" cols="51" placeholder='File Name...'></textarea>
    <textarea name="text" rows="13" placeholder='Num...'></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="String Upload">
  </form>
```

Comment: нельзя. а зачем такое надо?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, никак.

Comment: есть одна textarea и три батона. надо чтоб при нажатии и выполнении соотвествующего файла POST или как нибудь подругому в все 3  файла передавалось заполненое значения из textarea.

Comment: звучит как бред)) зачем это нужно? в файлы или в обработчики? в три файла запихать можно из одного обработчика, а накой три обработчика сразу запускать - не ясно

Comment: передаешь в один, в нем инклудишь 3 нужных )